# Find a Pattern in a Process Heap Memory

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, heap-memory

I am trying to scan all heap memory regions from a Process and scan a pattern in them.

I am using x64, and Windows 10. I am inside the target Process just for testing purposes.

My code is:

```
std::vector<__int64> matches;  // Holds all pattern matches

int FindPattern(__int64 patternAddress, char * mask) {

SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo; // Holds System Information
GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);

__int64 procMin = (__int64)sysInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress;  // Minimum memory address of process
__int64 procMax = (__int64)sysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress;  // Maximum memory address of process

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mBI, mBINext;
DWORD firstOldProtect = NULL;
DWORD secondOldProtect = NULL;
HMODULE hdll;

DWORD patternSize = (DWORD)strlen(mask);

while (procMin < procMax) {  // While still scanning memory

    VirtualQueryEx(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)procMin, &mBI, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));  // Get memory page details

    if (mBI.State == MEM_COMMIT) {

        VirtualProtect((LPVOID)procMin, mBI.RegionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &firstOldProtect);  // Set page to read/write/execute

        for (auto n = (__int64)mBI.BaseAddress; n < (__int64)mBI.BaseAddress + mBI.RegionSize; n += 0x01) {  // For each byte in this page

            if (n + patternSize > procMax) {  // If our pattern will extend past the maximum memory address, break
                break;
            }

            if (*(char*)n == (*(char*)patternAddress)) {  // If first byte of pattern matches current byte

                if (n + patternSize < (UINT)mBI.BaseAddress + mBI.RegionSize) {  // If entire length of pattern is within this page

                    if (ComparePattern((__int64)n, patternAddress, mask)) {  // Test if full pattern matches
                        matches.push_back((__int64)n);  // If it does, add it to the vector
                    }
                }
                else {  // If it isn't within the same page
                    VirtualQueryEx(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)(procMin + mBI.RegionSize), &mBINext, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));  // Same memory page stuff with next page

                    if (mBINext.State == MEM_COMMIT) {
                        VirtualProtect((LPVOID)(procMin + mBI.RegionSize), mBINext.RegionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &secondOldProtect);

                        if (ComparePattern((__int64)n, patternAddress, mask)) {
                            matches.push_back((__int64)n);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        VirtualProtect((LPVOID)procMin, mBI.RegionSize, firstOldProtect, NULL);  // Reset memory page state of first page

        if (secondOldProtect) {  // If we scanned into the second page
            VirtualProtect((LPVOID)procMin, mBINext.RegionSize, secondOldProtect, NULL);  // Reset memory page state of second page
            secondOldProtect = NULL;
        }
    }
    procMin = procMin + (__int64) mBI.RegionSize;  // Start scanning next page
     }
return 0;
}
```

Then the ComparePattern function is:

```cpp
bool ComparePattern(__int64 address, __int64 patternAddress, char * mask) {
int patternLen = strlen(mask);

for (auto i = 1; i < patternLen; i++) {
    if (mask[i] != *"?" && *(char*)(address + i) != *(char*)(patternAddress + i)) {  // Compare each byte of the pattern with each byte after the current scanning address
        return false;
    }
}
if (address != patternAddress) {  // Make sure we aren't returning a match for the pattern defined within your DLLMain
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

I retrieve several memory blocks, but I am not being able to retrieve the specific memory region/block where the pattern is located using this VirtualQueryEx code.

To test this and the weird part is that if I use the Heap APIs I am able to identify the memory allocated and the specified pattern:

```cpp
__int64 ReturnMachHeapAPI(__int64 patternAddress, char * mask) {

HANDLE hHeaps[250];

DWORD numHeaps = GetProcessHeaps(250, hHeaps);
unsigned long i;

if (numHeaps <= 250)
{
    for (i = 0; i < numHeaps; i++) {

        HeapLock(hHeaps[i]);

        PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY entry;
        memset(&entry, '\0', sizeof entry);

        bool found = false;

        while (!found && HeapWalk(hHeaps[i], &entry) != FALSE)
        {
                for (auto ii = (__int64)entry.lpData; ii < (__int64)entry.lpData + entry.cbData; ii += 0x01) {

                    if (ComparePattern((__int64)ii, patternAddress, mask)) {

                        return ii;
                    }
                }
        }
    HeapUnlock(hHeaps[i]);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any hints on why the VirtualQueryEx code is not working as expected. One point worth to mention is that my Process has several modules (DLLs) along with the main executable.

Thanks so much.

EDIT:
I re-wrote the VirtualQueryEx loop, using ReadProcessMemory now. It is working perfect now.

The working code is:

```cpp
char* InScan(char* pattern, char* mask, char* begin, unsigned int size)
{
//strlen the mask, not the pattern if you use the pattern
//you will get short length because null terminator
unsigned int patternLength = strlen(mask);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size - patternLength; i++)
{
    bool found = true;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < patternLength; j++)
    {
        if (mask[j] != '?' && pattern[j] != *(begin + i + j))
        {
            found = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found)
    {
        return (begin + i);
    }
}
return 0;
}

char * PatternScan(char* pattern, char* mask)
{

SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo; 
GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);

__int64 end = (__int64)sysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress; 

char* currentChunk = 0;
char* match = nullptr;
SIZE_T bytesRead;

while (currentChunk < (char *) end)
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
    int hr = GetLastError();

    if (!VirtualQueryEx(process, currentChunk, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    char* buffer = 0;

    if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS)
    {
        buffer = new char[mbi.RegionSize];
        DWORD oldprotect;
        if (VirtualProtectEx(process, mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect))
        {
            ReadProcessMemory(process, mbi.BaseAddress, buffer, mbi.RegionSize, &bytesRead);
            VirtualProtectEx(process, mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, oldprotect, &oldprotect);

            char* internalAddress = InScan(pattern, mask, buffer, bytesRead);

            if (internalAddress != 0)
            {
                //calculate from internal to external

                __int64 offsetFromBuffer = internalAddress - buffer;
                match = currentChunk + offsetFromBuffer;
                delete[] buffer;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    currentChunk = currentChunk + mbi.RegionSize;
    if (buffer) delete[] buffer;
    buffer = 0;
}
return match;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote the VirtualQueryEx loop, including the use of ReadProcessMemory and works perfect.

```
char* InScan(char* pattern, char* mask, char* begin, unsigned int size)
{

 unsigned int patternLength = strlen(mask);

 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size - patternLength; i++)

 {

 bool found = true;
 for (unsigned int j = 0; j < patternLength; j++)
 {
    if (mask[j] != '?' && pattern[j] != *(begin + i + j))
    {
        found = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (found)
{
    return (begin + i);
}
}

return 0;

}



char * PatternScan(char* pattern, char* mask)
{

SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo; 

GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);

__int64 end = (__int64)sysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress; 

char* currentChunk = 0;
char* match = nullptr;
SIZE_T bytesRead;

while (currentChunk < (char *) end)

{

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
int hr = GetLastError();

if (!VirtualQueryEx(process, currentChunk, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
{
    return 0;
}

char* buffer = 0;


if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS)
{
    buffer = new char[mbi.RegionSize];
    DWORD oldprotect;
    if (VirtualProtectEx(process, mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect))
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(process, mbi.BaseAddress, buffer, mbi.RegionSize, &bytesRead);
        VirtualProtectEx(process, mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, oldprotect, &oldprotect);

        char* internalAddress = InScan(pattern, mask, buffer, bytesRead);

        if (internalAddress != 0)
        {
            //calculate from internal to external

            __int64 offsetFromBuffer = internalAddress - buffer;
            match = currentChunk + offsetFromBuffer;
            delete[] buffer;
            break;
        }
    }
}

currentChunk = currentChunk + mbi.RegionSize;

if (buffer) delete[] buffer;
buffer = 0;
}

return match;

}
```